# Web page PHP version 7.1.23, MAMP and CLI 7.3.7 on macOS?

Tags: php, laravel, macos, mamp, macos-mojave

I'm running MAMP (Free) on macOS Mojave, and it states that the PHP version is 7.3.7, and that CLI's PHP version is 7.3.7 as well. However, when I run my Laravel application, phpversion() gives me 7.1.23.

I've spent an entire day using Google and trying out all the different fixes.

What I wanted to do was to edit the php.ini's line of max_filesize_upload from 2M to something higher, but each version i've changed still renders me with

> php.ini location: '/etc'
>
> loaded config file: (none)
>
> max_filesize_upload: 2M

on the web page. No issues with CLI and MAMP.

Please can anyone help me?

Comment: Why did you install MAMP when there is already a full stack preinstalled on macOS? By the way, you find two different PHP versions because you actually have two PHP's in your mac: one installed with MAMP, one which is the default (and probably the same goes with Apache). Open the terminal and run `php -v`. Then, run `whereis php` and look into those folders, you'll find two different php's instances.

Comment: ok yeah sorry i came from WAMP so i thought I needed MAMP. anyway looking into the dir listed on whereis php i can only find one php file. This is why it's very puzzling to me

Answer (score 0):

Your web server e.g. apache has different configuration from cli interface, try to run `php --ini` in terminal that should show current loaded configuration.

Comment: Yes, I did that `php --ini` and I'm getting the correct loaded configuration. But when I run my web app on MAMP, it shows a different configuration. Even on MAMP start page itself, I'm getting the correct php version, but not on my web app.